# Fail to run "startx" on a Guest OS through KVM

Tags: centos, startx

I have an AMD GPU S7150 and creat a pass-through VGA for a guest OS CentOS7.6 virtual machine.
The output for "lspci | grep AMD" on guest OS is as below,
00:09.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tonga XT GL [FirePro S7150].

The content for "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf" is as follows,

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier   "Card0"
    Driver       "amdgpu"
    BusID        "PCI:00:09:0"
EndSection
Section "Server Flags"
    Option       "IgnoreABI"
EndSection
```

When I run "startx" command on guest OS, I got an error message which is ***Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
    Fatal server error: no screens found***  in the file, /var/log/Xorg.0.log,

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
    [   228.461] Build Operating System:  3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 
    [   228.461] Current Operating System: Linux centos_client 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64
    [   228.461] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [   228.461] Build Date: 09 August 2019  03:27:09AM
    [   228.461] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.4-7.el7 
    [   228.461] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    [   228.461]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
    [   228.461] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    [   228.462] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jan  9 12:34:32 2020
    [   228.462] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    [   228.462] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
    [   228.463] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
    [   228.463] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
    [   228.463] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
    [   228.463] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
    [   228.463] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section". Using the first device section listed.
    [   228.463] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
    [   228.463] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section". Using a default monitor configuration.
    [   228.463] (**) Option "IgnoreABI"
    [   228.463] (**) Ignoring ABI Version
    [   228.463] (==) Automatically adding devices
    [   228.463] (==) Automatically enabling devices
    [   228.463] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
    [   228.463] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
    [   228.463] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
    [   228.463] (==) FontPath set to: catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d, built-ins
    [   228.463] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib64/xorg/modules,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
    [   228.463] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices. If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
    [   228.463] (II) Loader magic: 0x5653e35a2020
    [   228.463] (II) Module ABI versions:
    [   228.463]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    [   228.463]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
    [   228.463]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
    [   228.463]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
    [   228.464] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
    [   228.464] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
    [   228.479] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 1b36:0100:1af4:1100 rev 4, Mem @ 0xf4000000/67108864, 0xf8000000/67108864, 0xfc0b4000/8192, I/O @ 0x0000c240/32, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
    [   228.479] (--) PCI: (0@0:9:0) 1002:6929:1002:030c rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/2097152, 0xfc040000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000c100/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
    [   228.479] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
    [   228.480] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
    [   228.482] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [   228.482]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
    [   228.482]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
    [   228.482] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
    [   228.482] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
    [   228.482] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [   228.482]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 19.0.1
    [   228.482]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [   228.482]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
    [   228.482] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon: All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
    [   228.482] (--) using VT number 2
    [   228.486] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
    [   228.487] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
    [   228.487] (==) AMDGPU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
    [   228.487] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
    [   228.487] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
    [   228.487] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 888
    [   228.487] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
    [   228.487] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "AMD FirePro S7150" (ChipID = 0x6929)
    [   228.487] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
    [   228.487] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
    [   228.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
    [   228.488] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [   228.488]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
    [   228.488]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [   228.488] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
    [   228.488] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
    [   228.488] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
    [   228.495] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
    [   228.495] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
    [   228.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
    [   228.503] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [   228.503]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.1
    [   228.503]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [   228.557] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD FirePro S7150
    [   228.557] (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
    [   228.557] (==) AMDGPU(0): TearFree property default: auto
    [   228.557] (==) AMDGPU(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
    [   228.557] (II) AMDGPU(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
    [   228.557] (WW) AMDGPU(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
    [   228.557] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
    [   228.557] (II) AMDGPU(0): mem size init: gart size :16e34a000 vram size: s:1ff8d4000 visible:17fa9f000
    [   228.557] (II) AMDGPU(0): Video RAM: 8381264 kByte
    [   228.557] (==) AMDGPU(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
    [   228.557] (==) AMDGPU(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    [   228.557] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
    [   228.557] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
    [   228.557] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
    [   228.557] (EE) AMDGPU(0): No modes.
    [   228.557] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
    [   228.557] (II) UnloadSubModule: "glamoregl"
    [   228.557] (II) Unloading glamoregl
    [   228.557] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
    [   228.557] (II) Unloading fb
    [   228.563] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
    [   228.563] (EE) Fatal server error:
    [   228.563] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
    [   228.563] (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
    [   228.563] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
    [   228.563] (EE) 
    [   228.570] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

How to fix it?
Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread for a good answer: https://community.amd.com/thread/231483

Also, be aware that xorg configurations expect the 'BusID' to use decimals rather than hex. The output from 'lspci' is in hex.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to include the important points from the linked forum post? That way your answer will remain useful even if the forum becomes inaccessible.

Comment: @amdonlinux it is helpful, thanks.